# building for iOS, but linking in object file built for tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode12

ld: in Pods/AppCenter/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/AppCenter.xcframework/tvos-arm64/AppCenter.framework/AppCenter(MSACCommonSchemaLog.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file built for tvOS, file 'Pods/AppCenter/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/AppCenter.xcframework/tvos-arm64/AppCenter.framework/AppCenter'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This frameworks installed using Pods.
pod version 1.10.1
Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)
Swift version 5.3.2